# No Really Centos - Don't go to sleep

Tags: linux, power-management, centos

This is driving me nuts. I have the gnome settings in my CentOS 5.2 installation set to never go to sleep. But everyday I go away and come back in a few hours and the monitor is asleep and I have to click the mouse and keyboard to get the computer to wake up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Any sleep/power save settings in the BIOS setup?

Edit: Also found this generic note about Gnome/KDE ignoring the power save settings:

in file: /etc/rc.local add following:

```
sh -c 'setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0 < /dev/console > /dev/console 2>&1'
sh -c 'xset -dpms'
```

in file: /etc/init.d/local add following.

```
sh -c 'setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0 < /dev/console > /dev/console 2>&1'
```

Then as the user that runs KDE add a startup application and add the following command:

```
xset dpms 0 0 0 -dpms s off s 0 0 s noblank s noexpose
```

Comment: There are but I have them disabled. It's a core i7 and in the BIOS I have the C states disabled.

Comment: OK - I have edited my original answer with some more notes I've just found.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll check back later and see if this corrects it.

Comment: Darn, came in this morning and it was asleep.

Comment: Oh dear! That's me out of ideas.